# Capture model identifier for Apple Watch from WatchOS

Tags: c, swift, apple-watch, watchos

It looks like there aren't any documented official methods of obtaining the Apple Watch model from a watch app, but there is this post showing special use of `sysctlbyname`:

[How to determine the Apple Watch model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087330/how-to-determine-the-apple-watch-model)

Could anyone help me figure out why this function isn't working? It sometimes returns

> "Watc\t"

instead of the expected

> "Watch2,4"

Swift's sysctlbyname function seems to be this c function described here:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/sysctlbyname.c.auto.html

My code is copied from the swift answer in the SO post:

```
private func getWatchModel() -> String? {
   var size: size_t = 0
   sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
   var machine = CChar()
   sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
   return String(cString: &machine, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
} // Should return a string like "Watch2,4"
```

Comment: It'd probably be useful to see your code. Does it work on macOS? If not, it's probably easier to debug on macOS than on watchOS.

Comment: Also, your mention of "sometimes" makes me think that maybe you're misusing the buffer somehow - either freeing the buffer prematurely, or not allocating enough space for it.

Comment: @nneonneo Those are good thoughts. I have not tried testing on another platform. And I have added my code to the post (same as the code from from the linked SO post).

Comment: Honestly, I am not very familiar with how the buffer *could* be misused here and have trusted the original author. Would be very interesting to gain some insight though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never allocate a buffer to receive the machine string.
Change

```swift
var machine = CChar()
```

to

```swift
var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: size)
```

and you should be good to go!

Comment: Nice! This makes sense. I'm testing this now, but might take a while for me to confirm it does the trick and I can approve your answer. Thanks!
I should however point out this particular code doesn't compile... I changed it to Array<CChar>(repeating...

Comment: Whoops, typo! Will update! Should be `[CChar](repeating: 0, count: size) ` or `Array<CChar>...` as you point out.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. On simulator, it gives the Mac Machine. Is there anyway to test this on simulator ?

Comment: @claude31 I don't know of anyway (short of mocking out the call) to test it on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. In an app, I needed to detect if watch 7 (because of insets modifications). I finally used the screen bounds size to test it it is Watch 7 or not.