# Using SwiftUI on watchOS, how to align views to the navigation title?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I would like to align some content to the same inset the the navigation title uses.

On older watch devices, there is no inset, but on newer devices with the rounded corners, the title is inset, and for certain things I would like to align to the same inset.

The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/visual/layout/) talk about this margin, but I can't figure out how to use it.

[image]

**How can I modify this example to have the left edge of the Text and Button align with the Navigation Title?**

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Hello World")
            Button("Test") {}
        }
        .navigationTitle("Title")
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.scenePadding(.horizontal)`. That will automatically apply the padding you want on the larger watches. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/scenepadding(_:)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Not awesome that it requires watchOS 8, but oh well.

Answer (score -1):

Leading padding is simply (on the VStack):

```
        .padding(.leading, 9.5)
```

but you have to do it based on the watch model.
Here is an example of how to determine the watch model:
[How to determine the Apple Watch model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087330/how-to-determine-the-apple-watch-model)

And you might want to put this in a conditional view modifier:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962375/14351818

Comment: But, where does that value `9.5` come from, other than the one example given in the image I posted from the docs? How do I know what value to use for each device?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the current screen width:

```
 var screenWidth = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.width
```

and apply that (minus the desired margin) as a frame width to your VStack:

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading){
    
     Text("Hello World")
     Button("Test") {}
 }
 .frame(width: screenWidth - 25)
 .navigationTitle("Title")
```

This worked fine on 45mm and 40mm, but unfortunately still not quite there on the 38mm watch, so you might want to explicitly set different paddings/frames for smaller devices.

Comment: I guess what I want to know is where to get that device specific padding from. The navigation title obviously uses some value related to the safe area, how do I access the same value?

Comment: I think this might be helpful: [How to access safe area size in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120224/15051552)